# Magento - redirect to success page after registration

Tags: php, magento, action, registration

So, I'm new to magento and I've been trying to do some modification to the current code I got.
What I'm trying to do is redirect the user to a new page and show them some informations. What the code actually does is redirect the user to the login page and show him a message. I've found this piece of code on the AccountController but I don't know how I can create a new page and redirect the user to that page.

```
protected function _successProcessRegistration(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer $customer)
{
    $session = $this->_getSession();        

    if ($customer->isConfirmationRequired()) {
        /** @var $app Mage_Core_Model_App */
        $app = $this->_getApp();
        /** @var $store  Mage_Core_Model_Store*/
        $store = $app->getStore();
        $customer->sendNewAccountEmail(
            'confirmation',
            $session->getBeforeAuthUrl(),
            $store->getId()
        );
        $customerHelper = $this->_getHelper('customer');
        $session->addSuccess($this->__('Account confirmation is required. Please, check your email for the confirmation link. To resend the confirmation email please <a href="%s">click here</a>.',
            $customerHelper->getEmailConfirmationUrl($customer->getEmail())));
       $url = $this->_getUrl('*/*/index', array('_secure' => true)); //<---HERE!!!         
    } else {            
        $session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
        $session->renewSession();
        $url = $this->_welcomeCustomer($customer);
    }
    $this->_redirectSuccess($url);
    return $this;
}
```

How can I create a new action and define some html, and then redirect to it? I already tried to create a new function on this controller called successRegistrationAction(), but everytime I try to access it on the browser, I got redirected to login action.

Thanks in advance

*Edit:

Here's my function in AccountController.php:

```
public function registrationSuccessAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

Then I added this to customer.xml:

```
    <customer_account_registrationsuccess translate="label">
    <label>Customer Account Registration Success</label>
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="customer_registrationsuccess" template="customer/registrationSuccess.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</customer_account_registrationsuccess>
```

**Edit

My preDispatch function (added registrationSuccess to array):

```
public function preDispatch()
{
    // a brute-force protection here would be nice

    parent::preDispatch();

    if (!$this->getRequest()->isDispatched()) {
        return;
    }

    $action = $this->getRequest()->getActionName();
    $openActions = array(
        'create',
        'login',
        'logoutsuccess',
        'forgotpassword',
        'forgotpasswordpost',
        'resetpassword',
        'resetpasswordpost',
        'confirm',
        'confirmation',
        'registrationsuccess'
    );
    $pattern = '/^(' . implode('|', $openActions) . ')/i';

    if (!preg_match($pattern, $action)) {
        if (!$this->_getSession()->authenticate($this)) {
            $this->setFlag('', 'no-dispatch', true);
        }
    } else {
        $this->_getSession()->setNoReferer(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi yes you have to login first to go to your new action because by default if the user is not logged in it redirects you to the login oage. And can you please show your link hwow you are acesig your new action.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I updated the post. How can set login not required to this page. I access this url: http://localhost:8080/platinum/customer/account/registrationsuccess/ and it redirects to login page.

Comment: *How can set login not required to this page?

Comment: @RicardoNeves you can override public function preDispatch() to check login or not in your controller

Comment: @Dushyant Joshi, thank you. Now I can see the page but I'm can't see the html from registrationSuccess.phtml

Comment: @RicardoNeves, check if template is being called. flush cache and then also check

Comment: @Dushyant Joshi, how can I check if template is being called? All I see it's one column with "Lorem Ipsum" text where my "successRegistration" should be...

Comment: You can check by printing/deing something in the code? Or by enabling template path hints from backend. you can find this config at system->config-> developer

Comment: I created the registrationSuccess.phtml file manually. Should I create it from a specific place on admin page?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out... I was changing the wrong customer.xml
Now it's working.